# Xcode refuses to compile when trying to get property from custom object out of array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, object

I've been running into this problem a lot lately. I have an `NSMutableArray` called `tests` which is populated with instances of my custom class `Test`. I'm trying to access a property with the following method:

```
return [tests objectAtIndex:row].name;
```

However LLVM always throws an error and refuses to compile:

```
error: Semantic Issue: No member named 'name' in 'struct objc_object'
```

How do I tell the compiler that I'll be accessing a `Test` object and to let me compile the damned thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `objectAtIndex:` returns `id`, that is, a generic pointer, the compiler can't possibly know what method name to substitute for your property access `.name`.

You have to completely specify to the compiler what you want to do in this case. Either specify the exact method name:

```
[[tests objectAtIndex:row] name];
```

or specify the actual type of the object:

```
((Test *)[tests objectAtIndex:row]).name;
```

When you write `foo.bar`, the compiler has to look in `foo`'s class and find the method names associated with the property `bar`. Those are usually `bar`/`setBar:`, but they could be anything;* because of that ambiguity, the compiler needs to know the actual class of `foo`. Given only a generic pointer, it can't find that information.

<sub>The warning indicates that the compiler also checked whether the object on the left side of the `.` is a struct with a field called `name`. There isn't such a field, so the compiler does not know what you want it to do.</sub>

---

<sub>*E.g., 
    `@property(retain, setter=putThisValueIntoBar, getter=hamAndEggs) Bar * bar;`</sub>

Answer (score 5):

In order to use the dot notation for properties, the compiler needs to know the object's type.

You can send a message:

```
return [[test objectAtIndex:row] name];
```

Or you can cast the value returned by `objectAtIndex:`:

```
return ((Test*)[tests objectAtIndex:row]).name;
```

You might wonder why. The compiler needs to know the object's type because a property can designate any method to be the getter or the setter, not just the default pair of `name` and `setName:`, for example, this is usual with `BOOL` properties:

```
@property(getter=isEditable) BOOL editable;
```

So the compiler needs to know what property this is in order to generate the correct accessor calls.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an explicit cast should do the trick.

```
Test *test = [tests objectAtIndex:row];
test.name
```

Or send a message instead of calling a method.

```
[[tests objectAtIndex:row] name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can caste it like this:

```
return ((Test*)[tests objectAtIndex:row]).name;
```