# How to construct and use a name of variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-c create variables in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846728/objective-c-create-variables-in-a-loop)

I have 10 UILabels, for the sake of simplicity let it be label0, label1, ..., label9. Now, I'm implementing a loop and I need to access appropriate label from appropriate loop cycle:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
  label"i".text = "value of label i";
}
```

I need to construct variable name by binding loop cycle variable value to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: As well as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049175/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-variable-with-a-string-and-an-int, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164860/variable-name-from-string-in-obj-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164134/object-with-the-name-of-a-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888935/object-name-from-string-in-objective-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every `UILabel` you can keep a `tag`. `tag` is an `NSInteger`.

So it could essentially be your index number itself...

You can access the labels by calling `viewWithTag:` on a parent `UIView`.

Comment: I know that maybe having an array of labels and then iteration would be more elegant solution but I have ended saving some code and using you suggestion - tags :)

Comment: Check out my new answer below. There is a way you can do exactly what you want using NSClassFromString()

Answer (score 5):

As best I know, there isn't a way to do this like you suggest. However, you can populate an `NSMutableArray` with `UILabel`s and then call the object at index `i` to retrieve the `i`th label.

Create the `labelArray` (dynamically or statically), and then your `for` loop will be

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
  [[labelArray objectAtIndex:i] setText:@"value of label i"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an array of those labels, and iterate with index?

Answer (score -1):

I just ran across this today. This seems to be the original elegant solution you were looking for. It doesn't require any tags or special mutable arrays:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    ((UILabel *)NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%i", i])).text = @"value of label i";
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, however, I was unable to get it working. I put an IBAction with 2 code lines. Line "((UILabel *)NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%d", 1])).text = @"Value";" is not, but "self.label1.text = @"text";" is working. I have tried both using property label1 without ivar, and using ivar without a property, still it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll put together some test code today and push it somewhere for perusal.

Answer (score -2):

This is a fairly common use case. Typically this is solved my maintaining a map of strings to objects using an `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *labelMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
[labelMap setObject:[[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"label1"];
[labelMap setObject:[[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"label2"];
[labelMap setObject:[[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"label3"];
// etc
```

Then when you want to refer to an object by name:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){ 
   NSString *labelKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%i", i];
   [labelMap objectForKey: labelKey].text = "value of label i";
}
```

Comment: If this isn't using ARC, then you've got an extra retain on each of those labels and are likely leaking them.

Comment: Yep. You are correct. LOL -- so easy to move away from memory management once you start using ARC. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't actually help Centurion make it neater.

Comment: I disagree. [labelMap objectForKey: @"label1"].text is about as succinct as it gets. Even if he prefers something simplier -- using tag for example -- this is still a valid alternative. No idea why you would downvote it.

Comment: Should *valid* be the standard? Sure, it compiles, but it is absolutely horrible code. Fragile, verbose, and inefficient. As a solution it focuses on the wrong thing ("How do I concatenate a string and a number to an identifer?") versus the real issue ("How do I apply an operation to a series of objects?"). Using the `eval("label"+i)` trick is a hack in any language.

Comment: The property access on the generic pointer (`id`) returned from `objectForKey:` will cause a compiler warning. You will need to cast it: `((UILabel *)[labelMap objectForKey:labelKey]).text`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318505/xcode-refuses-to-compile-when-trying-to-get-property-from-custom-object-out-of-ar/6318584#6318584.