# variable name with value of int i

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, naming-conventions, value-of

i try made something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    UIButton *btn_i = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 * numberRowsOfMenu, 0 * heightOfRow, btnWidth, btnHeight)];
}
```

where `UIButton *btn_i` is `btn_` + value of `i`.

it is possible in Obj-C?

Comment: Your not going to get much milage out of these calculations `0 * numberRowsOfMenu, 0 * heightOfRow`

Comment: i know, it's not full parameter :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to construct and use a name of variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014855/how-to-construct-and-use-a-name-of-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean you want to wind up with variables with names like btn_0, btn_1, etc?

No, you cannot do this. You might be better off with something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    UIButton *b  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...];
    [butttons addObject:b];
    [b release];
}

// Now you can access the buttons array with indices, e.g:
UIButton *b = [buttons objectAtIndex:4];
```